# How to pass parameters into the method triggered by Timer.Elapsed?

Tags: c#, timer

I hope timer.Elapsed can trigger KeyAction, so that I can use the method in KeyAction to obtain the keyboard input content. But because keyPress was declared by myself, the parameters are different from those of Timer.Elapsed. I want to know how to successfully pass block1 that reports an error into KeyAction

```
public void TimerAction(object sender,ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
  this.KeyAction(block1, new KeyEventSrgs());  //error
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 500;

        KeyBord keyBord = new KeyBord();
        Block block1 = new Block();
        keyBord.KeyPress += block1.BlockMove;

        timer.Elapsed += keyBord.TimerAction;

        Console.Read();
    }
}
public class Block
{
    public void BlockMove(Block block, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("block move");
        Console.WriteLine(e.KeyInput);
    }
}
class KeyBord
{
    public event KeyEventHandler KeyPress;
    public void KeyAction(Block block, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Console.KeyAvailable)
        {
            ConsoleKey key = Console.ReadKey().Key;
            if (key == ConsoleKey.D)
            {
                e.KeyInput = ConsoleKey.D;
                Console.WriteLine(" e.KeyInput = ConsoleKey.D;");
            }
            this.KeyPress.Invoke(block, e);
        }
    }
    public void TimerAction(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.KeyAction(block1, new KeyEventArgs());
    }
}
public delegate void KeyEventHandler(Block block, KeyEventArgs e);
public class KeyEventArgs
{
    public ConsoleKey KeyInput { get; set; }
}
```

How to pass parameters into the method triggered by Timer.Elapsed?